# Semantics of sem_getvalue() in POSIX

Tags: c, linux, posix, semaphore, semantics

I need to resolve a synchronization problem using `PThreads.`
At some point in the code, one thread needs to know the number of threads blocked on a semaphore (as defined in `sempahore.h`).

When I took a look at the man pages of `sem_getvalue(sem_t *s, int *sval)`, it was stated that the returned value `sval` is `0` in Linux, but may have other semantics according to POSIX, i.e. the absolute value of `sval` is set to the number of threads blocked on semaphore `s`.

So I am looking for a Linux compiling option to make possible these alternative semantics.

I tried to simulate the number of threads blocked on a certain semaphore by keeping trace of an integer variable each time a thread executes `sem_wait()` on that semaphore.
But I am wondering about the correctness of this method especially for the race conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The question is inherently racy, and the `sem_getvalue` function, even if it returns a useful indication of the number of waiters, cannot provide any guarantee that the count is still correct when it returns and you use the resulting value. This sounds like an XY problem, so you should probably explain better what you imagine being able to achieve by having such a count.

Comment: Here is the situation:

Two sets of threads, let's says A and B are mutually exlusive between each others:
if a thread from A succeeds entering its critical section, then
any other thread from A can also enters its critical section, but not
the threads from B, and vice versa.

Comment: When the last thread from A exits its critical section, this later becomes empty.
At this point, threads from B can enter their respective critical sections
(obviously, threads from A can also enter but we assume here that priority is
given to threads from B).

Comment: In the exit protocol of A threads, there is a call to `sem_post()` on a semaphore
on which threads from B are blocked. So, the first thread from B will be released
and succeeds entering its critical section. 
However, in its exit protocol, it only sends one wakeup signal via `sem_post()` to
another thread from B. Thus, threads from B will enter their critical sections in turn
(which we consider here a performance issue because all the waiting threads from B can 
enter their critical sections instead of one-by-one thread).

Comment: Therefore, we need here to wakeup all the waiting threads from B instead of only one.
That's why we need to be able to run `sem_post()` as many times as the number of waiting threads.

Answer (score 2):

From the manual

> sem_getvalue() places the current value of the semaphore pointed to
>   sem into the integer pointed to by sval.

The semaphore is pointed by the first argument s (sem_t *s). There is a second argument in sem_getvalue (), sval, which is a pointer to an int. The value of semaphore is returned in this integer, a pointer to which is sval.

The function sem_getvalue () retunes 0 on success and -1 on error.

Comment: Please continue reading:  
"If one or more processes or threads are blocked  waiting  to  lock  the      semaphore  with  sem_wait(3), POSIX.1 permits two possibilities for the value returned in sval: either 0 is  returned;  or  a  negative  number whose  absolute  value  is  the  count  of  the number of processes and threads currently blocked in  sem_wait(3).   Linux  adopts  the  former behavior."